# Show data from SQL database in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I want to show data in grid view using 3 tables in SQL database.

first I created Model

```
public class common
    {

        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public Album Album { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    }
```

Then This is the Controller

```
 public ActionResult Show1()
    {
        var query = from a in DB.Album
                    join b in DB.Artists
                    on a.ArtistId equals b.ArtistId
                    join c in DB.Genre
                    on a.GenreId equals c.GenreId
                    where (b.ArtistId == 2)
                    select new common { Album = a, Artist = b, Genre = c };
        return View(query.ToList());
    }

}
```

After that this is my View

```
@model IEnumerable<test1.Models.common>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show1";
}

<h2>Show1</h2>

<div>

@{

  var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort:"Name");

}

@grid.GetHtml()

</div>
```

But it doesn't show any data?
How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you define the webgrid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an editorTemplate for your common object model
or use a for sentence and populate an html table

for example...

```
<table summary="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Account No.
            </th>
            <th>
                Customer Name
            </th>
            <th class="SingleCheckBox">
                Is Approved
            </th>
            <th  class="SingleCheckBox">
                Is Locked out
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Login
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); ++i)
{
    var item = Model[i];
    bool isSelected = item.AccountNo == selectedAccountNo;
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.RadioButton("selectedUserName", item.UserName, isSelected, new { name = "selectedUserName" })</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].UserName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td class="SingleCheckBox">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsApproved) 
        </td>
        <td class="SingleCheckBox">
            @if (item.IsLockedOut)
            {
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsLockedOut);
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsLockedOut);
            }
        </td>
        <td class="last-child">
            @(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(item.LastLoginDate, DateTimeKind.Utc), timeZoneInfo).ToString())
        </td>
    </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i think you missed the question... AKA the WebGrid part

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best answer to your question is yet another question: "***Why a WebGrid?***"

If you refer to the default functionality of a newly created MVC project, you will see that the Index.cshtml will use a table (as suggested in the answer provided by **@hagensoft**).  It has been my experience that when items are properly scaffolded for an MVC project in Visual Studio I have had to do very little work to get the list of models to display nicely, even paginated if necessary.

To make better use of pagination, if that is what you are after, I have made great use of the PagedList.MVC package available through NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/).  There is plenty of documentation related to the functionality provided by PagedList, and PagedList, along with the table suggestion/default view behavior with new MVC projects in Visual Studio, works wonders along side of any sorting, searching, or similar functionality that you would like to provide within your app.

A fantastic tutorial that I refer to about Sorting, Filtering, and Paging can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

If you are insistent about using a WebGrid/GridView, I would suggest perhaps moving the database call out of the controller and directly into the Razor view itself, or try sending back an ObervableCollection<>, not a List<>, of a dedicated ViewModel from the Controller.

The moral of the story here is to not venture far from the provided path.  Try to use the tools that are given to you and follow the default format for MVC projects.

Answer (score 0):

First Add Jquery in your view

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you want to style Add Style

```
<style type="text/css">
            .webGrid { margin: 4px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 500px;  background-color:#FCFCFC;}
            .header { background-color: #C1D4E6; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }
            .webGrid th, .webGrid td { border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 5px; }
            .alt { background-color: #E4E9F5; color: #000; }
            .gridHead a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
            .description { width:auto}
            .select{background-color: #389DF5}
        </style>
```

Add Model in your view

```
 @{
        test1.Models.common Common = new test1.Models.common();
    }
```

Add Code in your view

```
 @{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
            <div id="gridContent">
            @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                    headerStyle: "header",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                    selectedRowStyle: "select",
                    columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("Id", "Id"),
                    grid.Column("Name", "Name"),
                    grid.Column("Description", "Description"),

             )) 
        @if (grid.HasSelection)
             {
                 common= (test1.Models.common)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;
                 <b>Id</b> @common.Artist.Id<br />
                 <b>Name</b>  @common.Album.Name<br />
                 <b>Description</b> @common.Album.Description<br />

             }
    </div>
```

Edit this section According to your Model details

```
@if (grid.HasSelection)
         {
             common= (test1.Models.common)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;
             <b>Id</b> @common.Artist.Id<br />
             <b>Name</b>  @common.Album.Name<br />
             <b>Description</b> @common.Album.Description<br />

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your model it doesn't show anything. Webgrid doesn't know how to render your Artist or Album or Genre table model. You need to create new model with basic variables like string, int, decimal

```
public ActionResult Show1()
{
    var query = from a in DB.Album
                join b in DB.Artists
                on a.ArtistId equals b.ArtistId
                join c in DB.Genre
                on a.GenreId equals c.GenreId
                where (b.ArtistId == 2)
                select new common { AlbumName = a.AlbumName, ArtistName = b.ArtistName, GenreName = c.GenreName /* ... other props */ };
    return View(query.ToList());
}

public class common
{

    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }
    //you need to use basic variables like string, int, decimal...

}
```